# Data cardinality is ambiguous(Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got my dataset from mnist dataset,

```
train_images = train_images.astype("float32")/255.0
test_images = test_images.astype("float32")/255.0

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size = 64, epochs = 10, verbose =2)
network.evaluate(test_images,test_labels, batch_size = 64, verbose=2)
```

I got this error during training

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:   x sizes: 10000   y sizes: 60000 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples .
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like train_images and train_labels aren't the same size. Where did you get train_labels and test_labels? Can you post the full code so that we can reproduce?

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this error is,

"The number of rows in the input dataset(x) are not matching with the corresponding rows in the labeled output dataset(y)".
Or probably, there is an issue while splitting the `mnist` dataset into a training and testing dataset.

The right way of fetching input and labeled dataset of training and testing dataset is:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

print("Training dataset:", train_images.shape, train_labels.shape)
print("Testing dataset:", test_images.shape, test_labels.shape)
```

Output: (The number of rows should be equal for the input and output set)

```
Training dataset: (60000, 28, 28) (60000,)  
Testing dataset: (10000, 28, 28) (10000,)
```

Please check this attached [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/9104000dd253217185ff9e8f9efa9383/71448700.ipynb) for your reference.